# Rendering a react component variable with react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v6 and I want to render a component stored in a variable. In earlier versions of react router they have component props that allows you to render a component using a variable without the JSX syntax, however the V6 doesn't allow that.

```js
import ComponentName from "components/ComponentName"
...
const component = ComponentName;
...
<Router path="..." element={component } />
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question or title. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

you can call your variable as a function

```js
import ComponentName from "components/ComponentName"
...
const component = ComponentName;
...
<Router path="..." element={component()} />
```